# How to edit Firewall rules in code successfully on a Worker Role Instance?

Tags: c#, azure-worker-roles, windows-firewall

I'm trying some code that works locally but it doesn't work on my cloud instance.  I assume it may be permissions related, but I'm unable to fix it yet.  Here is what I have which works when I debug my worker role locally, but nothing happens when it is published (on staging right now).

```
string strCmdText = string.Format("advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"BlockU\" protocol=any dir=in action=block remoteip={0}", ip);

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh.exe", strCmdText);
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
try
{
    Process.Start(psi);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I have also tried using the

```
psi.Verb = "runas";
```

but that did not help either.

Finally I tried the firewall api like so.  This also worked locally, but threw an access denied error on the last line.

```
INetFwRule2 inboundRule = (INetFwRule2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
 inboundRule.Enabled = true;
 inboundRule.RemoteAddresses = ip;
 inboundRule.InterfaceTypes = "All";
 inboundRule.Protocol = (int)NetFwTypeLib.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_ANY;
 inboundRule.Name = "BlockU Part 2";
 //inboundRule.Profiles = currentProfiles;
 inboundRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;
 // Now add the rule

 INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
 firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(inboundRule);
```

Comment: I found an answer through an old post just now.  I was not running it as an admin, it is a dedicated service (i believe).

Comment: Try running the wroker role with admin privileges, modify the csdef file and add the following: 
<Runtime executionContext ="elevated" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found over on the [azure forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a38cb34a-2c0a-4619-aa00-edb4a5c04881/worker-role-how-to-open-firewall-ports-?forum=windowsazuredevelopment) that I need to enable my Worker Role to run with elevated privileges.  This can be done in the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file by adding the following attribute to the WorkerRole element

```
<WorkerRole name="CloudService.Worker" vmsize="ExtraSmall"
            enableNativeCodeExecution="true">
```

and also by adding a

```
<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
```

element inside the WorkerRole element.

Both sets of code ran successfully with the configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an interesting post in msdn blogs that uses a library which simplify the configuration of firewall rule, may be it will resolve your issue,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx

on a

Comment: I appreciate the link - it may help others who stop by here.  That is the library I am using in my 2nd example.  The actual .dll for that library was already loaded on my machine in the c:\windows\system32\FirewallAPI.dll  Hopefully that helps someone too.